# Using telerik RadEditor convert image to stream and display it to browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radeditor

I have placed a radeditor control in my aspx page and copy pasted some content from microsoft word to it that was containing an image along with some text data. Then I saved the data. I marked that it was converting the image to stream. The string I have noticed for the image was something like this :

```
<img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,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" /><br />
```

I copied this source and pasted it in another html file and run it in browser, it was showing the image i have copied.

Now, I have copied some other text along with image from some other website  (browser)  and pasted it to editor, It was displaying image tag along with path.

What I want is copy and paste image from browser to editor should convert it like above instead it having src="domain/path/filename.extesion".

Is it possible? Another solution is to get all the image tags from content() method and replace its src attribute value. But for this I have to fetch the image from URL, convert it to byte or stream (i don't know how you people are doing it) , make in encode with base 64 and then replace it with actual source.

Can anyone help??

Thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved it my self :

For this I have added `HTMLAgilityPack.dll` in bin folder and added its reference in project. Added a `telerik RadEditor` control in the page. 
Then created a method `parseHtmlToImageSource(string html)` that accepts html as string and returns modified string with images in stream formate. 
On clicking submit button, the following code will be executed and will give you bites of whole HTML page which you can store into server `varbinary` data type.

```
protected void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            try
            {
                string html = parseHtmlToImageSource(editor.Content);
                byte[] array = new GetBytes(html);
        }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex
            }
}

private string parseHtmlToImageSource(string html)
{
            try
            {
                string modifiedHTML = html;
                HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(html);

                var srcTags = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
                if (srcTags != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]"))//select only those img that have a src attribute..ahh not required to do [@src] i guess
                    {
                        string value = item.Attributes["src"].Value.ToString();

                        if (!(value.Contains("data:image/") && value.IndexOf("base64") > 0))
                        {
                            string extension = Path.GetExtension(item.Attributes["src"].Value.ToString().ToLower());

                            if (extension.Contains("."))
                            {
                                extension = extension.Remove(extension.IndexOf("."), extension.IndexOf(".") + 1);
                            }

                            item.Attributes["src"].Value = makeImageSrcData(item.Attributes["src"].Value.ToString(), extension);

                            modifiedHTML = modifiedHTML.Replace(value, item.Attributes["src"].Value.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }

                //doc.ToString();

                //doc.Save("yourFile");//dont forget to save

                return modifiedHTML;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
}


private string makeImageSrcData(string url, string extension)
{
            try
            {
                WebResponse result = null;
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

                // Get the content
                result = request.GetResponse();

                Stream rStream = result.GetResponseStream();
                byte[] rBytes = ReadFully(rStream);

                return "data:image/" + extension + ";base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(rBytes, Base64FormattingOptions.None);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
}

public static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    try
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return bytes;
    }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                throw ex;
        }
}

public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int read;
                    while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
}
```

You can also convert bytes to string using following method while reading data or placing it to editor :

for example :

```
protected void getData()
{
    try
        {   // Make a code to get the data from data base here and then for varbinary fild I have used "fieldName"
        string contents = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["fieldName"];
        editor.Content = new GetString(excelContents);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
        {
                throw ex;
        }
}

public static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
{
    try
        {
            char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
            return new string(chars);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
        {
                throw ex;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this asks the same question: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/editor/conver-image-to-stream-how.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Dev's answer solved my problem, but as an interim (quick and easy) solution you can use OnClientPasteHtml to prevent pasting of base64 encoded images:

```
<telerik:RadEditor ID="RadEditor1" runat="server" OnClientPasteHtml="OnClientPasteHtml">
</telerik:RadEditor> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnClientPasteHtml(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_value().indexOf(";base64,") > -1) {
                args.set_cancel(true);
            }
        }
    </script>
```